# Hot deck imputation for cleaning data

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I am importing data for creating a machine learning classifier and at the moment i am cleaning the data.
There are missing values within the data and are marked NA

```
missingData = {{2, 4, 0.986`,RGBColor[0.7931811599535044, 0.9794035526034883, 
0.1736111262263147]}, {1, 5, 0.0701`,RGBColor[0.4966346762097671, 0.42506700252493146, 
0.6020480735371379]}, {2, 3, 0.356`,RGBColor[0.17005048612802431, 0.32340985960079616, 
0.5088057001465967]}, {1, 5, 0.859`,RGBColor[0.26079904402442433, 0.6645405387012917, 
0.626762001873512]}, {1, 7, 0.87`,RGBColor[0.35006141637857935, 0.241784130785629, 
0.8287210560502678]}, {1, 5, 0.372`,RGBColor[0.6040242604212316, 0.2495041618176539, 
0.1612746936530718]}, {2, "NA", 0.356`,RGBColor[0.5812714623512671, 0.2969407447142949, 
0.49572510310649687]}, {1, 3, 0.751`,RGBColor[0.6124614477104853, 0.378535780066783, 
0.878636444824388]}, {1, 1, 0.157`,RGBColor[0.664181976745267, 0.25405278277799814, 
0.12343422551954197]}, {1, 1, "NA",RGBColor[0.5918739987770754, 0.7079781022288523, 
0.7994674398394699]}, {2, 3, 0.685`, "NA"}, {2, 5, 0.458`,RGBColor[0.8929266436889802, 0.6764412122657568, 
0.1876179631453354]}, {2, 4, 0.0106`,RGBColor[0.5746966560731546, 0.5532290683267522, 
0.6433151858365447]}, {1, 0, 0.697`,RGBColor[0.4036028221713692, 0.6499596806079162, 
0.1976339227708881]}, {2, 6, 0.0239`,RGBColor[0.2242880379356622, 0.11173047800711289, 
0.0796914387814045]}}
```

I am trying to use hot deck imputation(HDI) to replace the missing values

```
copyOfMissingData=missingData
```

**The Problem**
   I am able to use HDI to replace only one of the variables with the follwing input
Listing the samples with missing data

```
missing = Cases[copyOfMissingData, {___, "NA"}]
```

List the good samples (with no missing data) :

```
goodSamples = DeleteCases[copyOfMissingData, {___, "NA",___}]
```

Find the sample that is nearest to the sample "missing", based on feature values in columns 1, 2 and 3 :

```
Nearest[goodSamples[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], First[missing][[{1, 2,3}]]]
```

Set up Nearest to return the color (data from column 4) for the sample that is nearest to "missing" for values in columns 1, 2 and 3 :

```
samples = #[[{1, 2, 3}]] -> #[[4]] & /@ goodSamples

replacement = Nearest[samples, First[missing][[{1, 2, 3}]]]
```

Replace the missing data with the feature value from the nearest sample :

```
copyOfMissingData[[All, 4]] /."NA" -> RGBColor[0.17005048612802431`, 0.32340985960079616`,0.5088057001465967]
```

**However** this works only for replacing one of the missing variables. when i try to use this code to replace all missing variables, i encounter the following.
**The only change i make is in the missing input, where i include the rest of the variables**

```
missing = Cases[copyOfMissingData, {___, "NA", ___}]
goodSamples = DeleteCases[copyOfMissingData, {___, "NA", ___}]
```

Find the sample that is nearest to the sample "missing", based on feature values in columns 1, 2 and 3

```
Nearest[goodSamples[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], First[missing][[{1, 2,3}]]]
```

This is where i encounter the following error message

Nearest::neard: The default distance function does not give a real numeric distance when applied to the point pair {2,NA,0.356} and {2,4,0.986}.

What im aiming to do is replace all of the missing variables in this dataset using hot deck imputation.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Rather than using HDI have you considered using `LearnDistribution` and `SynthesizeMissingValues` see [this](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/high-level-machine-learning/synthesize-missing-values-in-numeric-data.html?product=language) for examples.

Comment: Hello Rohit, thank you for reply. I was able to use LearnDistribution successfully, thanks for the tip. At the moment I am trying to learn different methods of cleaning data so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
noMissing = Select[FreeQ["NA"]][missingData];
```

For versions before 12.0,

```
ClearAll[dist, nearestF, hdi]
dist[u : {__?NumericQ}, v : {__?NumericQ}] := EuclideanDistance[u, v]
dist[{u__?NumericQ, c1_RGBColor}, {v__?NumericQ, c2_RGBColor}] :=  dist[{u}, {v}] + 
    ColorDistance[c1, c2]

nearestF[i_] := First@Nearest[Drop[noMissing, None, {i}] -> "Index", #, 1, 
    DistanceFunction -> dist] &

hdi = Map[# /. p : {__} /; Not[FreeQ[p, "NA"]] :> 
   Module[{pos = First[PositionIndex[p]@"NA"]},
     Replace[p, "NA" -> noMissing[[nearestF[pos][Drop[p, {pos}]], pos]], All]] &];

Row[Panel[Grid[#]] & /@ {missingData, hdi @ missingData}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

For version 12.0, TIL from @Rohit's comment the function [`SynthesizeMissingValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SynthesizeMissingValues.html).

Comment: OMG, TIL @kglr does not know every function in WL. :-(